# Carrierwave doesn't save files or enter records in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am trying to store an uploaded file with Carrierwave in my Rails application. I have a model that saves data for a (podcast) episode called `Episode`. Each episode should have a column `upload` for an audio file associated with that episode. To do this, i created an uploader called `EpisodeUploader` like this:

```
rails generate uploader Episode
```

> Note: This is a bit confusing. I have a Model named *Episode* which
>   has a column named *upload*, but the uploader is called Episode too
>   (which will end up named *EpisodeUploader* using the generator.

To make my model use the `EpisodeUploader` I added a column named `upload`

```
rails g migration add_upload_to_episodes upload:string
```

Then, in my Episode model I mounted the uploader

```
mount_uploader :upload, EpisodeUploader
```

In my form I added a file field like this:

```
= f.file_field :upload
```

Now when I upload a file, no error or anything is thrown, but the file is not stored on my disk and no data has been written to the database.

What am I doing wrong? Is it maybe the naming thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. I added the uploader after I scaffolded the model. The scaffolding operation generated this method in my `Episode` model

```
def episode_params
  params.require(:episode).permit(:podcast_id, :name, :description)
end
```

I had to add :upload to the list of permitted params:

```
def episode_params
  params.require(:episode).permit(:podcast_id, :name, :description, :upload)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have pemissions to write that file.

Comment: And you have to make sure your carrierwave is configured correctly.